# convert char to char such as encryption

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

How to make a simple encryption decryption?
2 pieces of make edit box and a button in the project, 
then I write something in `editbox1` and then press `button1` in `editbox2` generate some keys in such settings ..

> a: = 1;  b: = 2;  c: = 3;  d: = 4;  e: = 5;  f: = 6;  g: = 7;  h: = 8;
>   i: = 9;  j: = 0;  k: = #;  l: = $;  m: =%;  n: = ~;  o: = *;

and then with the symbol say
`a: = 1;` it means: `a is 1 if at editbox2`

letters (A) be the number 1 subparagraph (B) be the number 2 subparagraph (C) be the number 3 simple conversion .. **so make a simple substitution cipher and decryption**

Comment: And how is this related to TEdit and TButton? This is a simple string conversion

Comment: You are looking for a [substitution cipher](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher)

Comment: Ok, then where is the problem? What have you tried so far (code) and where did you get stuck? (Please do not add the code as a comment, put it in the question)

Comment: Because you asked a delphi related question, we all had expected some kind of delphi code ...

Comment: BTW this is not "letter to number" it is just "char to char"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple substitution cipher

```
const
  CPlain = 'abcdefghijklmno';
  CCrypt = '1234567890#$%~*';

function Transcode( const AStr, ALookupA, ALookupB : string ): string;
var
  LIdx, LCharIdx : integer;
begin
  // the result has the same length as the input string
  SetLength( Result, Length( AStr ) );
  // walk through the whole string
  for LIdx := 1 to Length( AStr ) do
  begin
    // find position of char in LookupA
    LCharIdx := Pos( AStr[LIdx], ALookupA );
    // use the char from LookupB at the previous position
    Result[LIdx] := ALookupB[LCharIdx];
  end;
end;

function Encrypt( const AStr : string ) : string;
begin
  // from plain text to crypt text
  Result := Transcode( AStr, CPlain, CCrypt );
end;

function Decrypt( const AStr : string ) : string;
begin
  // from crypt text to plain text
  Result := Transcode( AStr, CCrypt, CPlain );
end;
```